# Pulling iOS files from application sandbox with AWS Device Farm XCTest

Tags: ios, xctest, aws-device-farm

I am running an XCTest on AWS Device Farm. I am specifying the path to pull here:

[image: Device paths configuration]

When I run the test on a local device I can see the file in the app sandbox (Documents directory).

[image]

I can see in the AWS Device Farm application logs that the file is being written:

```
Results at: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D61EC683-3591-4B3B-84F1-CDE49B112ABB/Documents/test-data/ios-render-test-runner-metrics.html
```

However, when I check the 'customer artifacts logs' I can see that something is going wrong.

When I specify `Documents/test-data` as a path to pull:

```
Now attempting to pull iOS customer files from Documents/test-data
Failed to attach some or all files from /tmp/scratchrwHtVL.scratch/app-sandbox-mount-11sBT_/Documents/test-data
```

When I specify `Documents/test-data/ios-render-test-runner-metrics.html` as a path to pull.

```
Now attempting to pull iOS customer files from Documents/test-data/ios-render-test-runner-metrics.html
Failed to attach some or all files from /tmp/scratch3m4MLc.scratch/app-sandbox-mount-m18X0D/Documents/test-data/ios-render-test-runner-metrics.html
```

Any ideas what could be happening here or how I could debug this? Yes, I did enable iTunes file sharing, which AWS Device Farm requires. `Info.plist`:

```
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```